# Daily estimate value

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a start time and a constantly increasing value. I'm trying to get a daily average of this increasing value. Problem is I can't think of how to get a decimal from the DateTime to multiply with the value.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if you want to calculate average, why do you need "decimal from the DateTime"? You can add all the values at different points in time and divide by the total number of those values.

Comment: You need to share the sample data and the expected output. Also what attempt you made to solve this issue? You need to share the code you wrote for this.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the percentage increase over the course of each day? Or do you want the actual average of the value (like `(endValue - startValue) / 2`)?

Comment: Don't get a decimal from DateTime, just get the value itself daily. From the differences between the values you collect you can estimate an overall average value.

Comment: I wanted to get a daily amount. Like lets say the start time was 12 hours ago and the value is 24 the daily estimate would be 48.

Comment: Can you please show a [MCVE] at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` objects can be subtracted from each other, to give a `TimeSpan`. A TimeSpan has a `.TotalDays` property, which represents the number of days between the two times that the TimeSpan was calculated from. It is important that you subtract the earlier time from the later time. The time now, minus a time 12 hours ago, gives a TimeSpan whose `.TotalDays` is 0.5

```
var val = 24;
var startTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12); //fake 12h ago
var dailyAvg = val / (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalDays;
```

A TimeSpan also has a .Days property, but this isn't what you want, because it's an integer of the whole number of days.. the properties with names like .TotalXXX give decimals representing the entire TimeSpan in wholes and fractions of the named unit. The properties without the word Total in, would be used in formatted strings like:

```
var ts = DateTime.Now - messagePostingDate;
var ago = "Message posted " + ts.Days + " days and " + ts.Hours + " hours ago";
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for.